# Google Maps flashes 0,0 water before panning to marker/polyline of interest (using gmaps4rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gmaps4rails

I'm using gmaps4rails to display a single marker, but I can't get it to not show a flash of lat/lon 0,0 water before panning over to the marker.

My (coffeescript) code is very simple:

```
handler = Gmaps.build('Google')
handler.buildMap { provider: {}, internal: { id: 'my-map-id' } }, ->
  marker = handler.addMarker
    lat: 41.0
    lng: -96.0
  marker.panTo()
  handler.getMap().setZoom(14)
```

The map displays blue water then quickly jumps over to the desired location.  I've tried using the bounds-oriented methods instead of the `marker.panTo()`, with the same results:

```
handler.bounds.extendWith(marker)
handler.fitMapToBounds()
handler.getMap().setZoom(14)
```

It seems like I need to either prevent display of the map until the marker and location is set, or I need to add the markers in earlier.  Neither of which I've figured out how to do.

Comment: actually: either you know the center in advance and you pass it in the `provider` object, or you rely on google maps to do it but it will flash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the quick tip from @apneadiving, this took care of it:

```
lat = 41.0
lng = -96.0

options =
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)
  zoom: 14

handler = Gmaps.build('Google')
handler.buildMap { provider: options, internal: { id: 'contact-map' } }, ->
  marker = handler.addMarker
    lat: lat
    lng: lng
```